# Ant Tokenizer: Selecting an individual Token

Tags: java, ant, build-process

I have the following ant task:

```
<loadfile property="proj.version" srcfile="build.py">
    <filterchain>
        <striplinecomments>
            <comment value="#"/>
        </striplinecomments>
        <linecontains>
            <contains value="Version" />
        </linecontains>
    </filterchain>
</loadfile>
<echo message="${proj.version}" />
```

And the output is

```
 [echo] config ["Version"]          = "v1.0.10-r4.2"
```

How do I then use a tokenizer to get only `v1.0.10-r4.2`, the equivalent of

```
| cut -d'"' -f4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [`containsregex`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#containsregex) element within your `filterchain` as [`tokenfilter`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#tokenfilter).

This should filter any line with `"Version"` in it, and return as content the only group captured: '`vx.y.zz....`'

<sup><containsregex
            pattern="^.*?\"Version\".*\"(v[^\"]+?)\".*"
            replace="\1" />
does not work.

May be     <containsregex
            pattern='^.*?"Version".*"(v[^\"]+?)".*'
            replace="\1" />
could work (with single quotes for the `parameter` attribute, allowing for non-escaped double-quotes inside the parameter value)</sup>

Actually the [OP John Oxley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/24108/john-oxley) provides a working solution with the double quotes (`\"`) replaced by `&quot;`:

```
<containsregex
        pattern="^.*?&quot;Version&quot;.*&quot;(v[^&quot;]+?)&quot;.*"
        replace="\1" />
```

Comment: Thank you. Almost worked.  I had to use &quot; to escape the " and then it worked perfectly.

Comment: @John: thank you for the feedback. Do you mean replace every double quotes by &quot; as in: `pattern="^.*?\&quot;Version\&quot;.*\&quot;(v[^\&quot;]+?)\&quot;.*"` ?

Comment: You don't escape the &.  This is what works.  `pattern="^.*?&quot;Version&quot;.*&quot;(v[^&quot;]+?)&quot;.*"`

Comment: @John: thank you for this precision. I have update my answer to reflect the right pattern syntax.